# getting to another screen from listview row

Tags: android, listview

In the following code, I want to set Onclick Listeners on some "elements" of my row. where should I place the setOnclick listener code? In the activity code or in the adapter? I suppose the first, but in that case how will I identify which row has been selected 
(each row is supposed to get me to different views)?

Java code:

```
List<String[]> info=new ArrayList<String[]>();
         String[] names_info=new String[5];
         String[] phones_info=new String[5];
         String[] map_info=new String[5];
         String[] web_info=new String[5];
         String[] photos_info=new String[5];
for(int i=0;i<names_info.length;i++)
     {
         info.add(new String[]{names_info[i],phones_info[i],map_info[i],web_info[i],photos_info[i]});
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < info.size(); i++) {
       Log.d("TAG", "item " + i + 
                " name:" +  info.get(i)[0] + 
                " info:" + info.get(i)[1]);
    }
     FacilitiesAdapter adapter = new FacilitiesAdapter(this,info,want_info_display,want_phone_display,want_photos_display);
     //System.out.println(info[0]);
     setListAdapter(adapter);

EDIT

 ListView lv = getListView();



lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
             // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) arg1).getText(),
            //Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Intent i33 = new Intent(HotelsScreen.this,AbousUsScreen.class);
          i33.putExtra("position", arg2);
            System.out.println(arg2);
            System.out.println(info.get(arg2)[0]);

        startActivity(i33);             
        }
    });
```

I see results in Log, so that means that my info is getting its result normally.

This is my adapter.

```
public class FacilitiesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String[]> {
    private final Context context;
    List <String[]> dataList;

    public FacilitiesAdapter(Context context, List<String[]> dataList, int need_phone, int need_info, int need_photos)  {
        super(context, R.layout.expand_row);
        this.context = context;
        this.dataList = dataList;
        //this.tracks_condition=tracks_condition;
        //this.count=count;
    }
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expand_row, parent, false);
            System.out.println("I am here");
            String[] data = dataList.get(position);
            String name=data[0];
            TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            System.out.println("I am in the adapter "+name);
            textView.setText(name);
            return rowView;
     }
}
```

EDIT 1: 
am I supposed now to see in every item I click its position and its name? Cause I see nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can be as simple as something alone these lines:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
      long arg3)
  {
    Intent i33 = new Intent(MyScreen.this,OtherScreen.class);
    i33.putExtra("position", position);
    startActivity(i33);
  }
});
```

Comment: this would go probably go in your onCreate

Comment: Ok with this. And how can I pass as a parameter the text's ids (both name and info, i order to use them so as to know whick screen to open

Comment: if `onItemClick` has access to the same `dataList` that the adapter has, it can get the data it needs and then use `i33.putExtra(...)` similar to that shown above

Answer (score 0):

I think your biggest problem will be figuring out how to map a row to the appropriate screen. If you can do this, you can set up a Map object with all the mappings.

In your adapter, you can then use setTag() on the view and pass it what you get back from the Map, then creating a new Intent from it.

```
//In your adapter's getView() method...
Class activityClass = rowToActivityMap.get(someRowAttribute);
view.setTag(activityClass);

//In your click listener...
Class activityClass = (Class)view.getTag();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, activityClass);
startActivity(intent);
```